# Asymptotic formula for fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, semigroups-of-operators

For the solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda u^\epsilon - \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \Delta u^\epsilon = 0 &\text{in } \Omega \\
u^\epsilon=1 & \text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
Varadhan proved that
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} - \epsilon \log u^\epsilon = \sqrt{2\lambda} \mathrm{dist} (x,\partial \Omega). $$

Can we prove that a similar asymptotic formula holds for
$$
\begin{cases}
u^\epsilon + \epsilon (-\Delta)^s u^\epsilon = 0 &\text{in } \Omega \\
u^\epsilon=1 & \text{on } \mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [fractional Laplacian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what hypotheses are imposed on $\Omega$ - is some regularity required?

Comment: @LeoMoos In Varadhan's paper it says that $\Omega$ is open, but I don't know if this is truly enough or if you also need to assume more regularity (which I would be ok with)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Probabilistic approach

I have to think about the right reference, but things are very much different in the non-local case.

---

The solution $u = u^\epsilon$ can be written in probabilistic terms as
$$ u(x) = \mathbb E^x e^{-k \tau_D} ,$$
where $k = \lambda / \epsilon$, $\tau_D$ is the first exit time from the open set $D = \Omega$ (when probability enters, I prefer to use $D$ rather than $\Omega$ for the domain) for the corresponding isotropic stable Lévy process $X_t$, and $\mathbb E^x$ is the expectation corresponding to the process started at $x$.

---

In the local case, the Brownian motion is very unlikely to exit $D$ quickly. Roughly speaking, for $t$ small, the probability that $\tau_D < t$ is comparable to the probability that $X_t \notin D$, which in turn is roughly $$\exp(-\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)^2 / (4 t)).$$ Thus, $u(x)$ can be estimated from below by (again roughly)
$$ \exp(-k t - \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)^2 / (4 t)) . $$
Optimizing with respect to $t$ leads to a lower bound of the form
$$ \exp(-\sqrt{k} \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega) k t) , $$
which is off by a factor $2$ in the exponent compared to Varadhan's result.

---

Now let us consider the non-local case and the jump-type stable process. In this case the probability that $\tau_D < t$ is quite large: it is of the order $$c_{N,s} t \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz + O(t^2) $$ (this is comparable to $t \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)^{-2s}$ given some regularity of the complement of $\Omega$). Therefore, we immediately get a lower bound for $u(x)$ of the form
$$ t e^{-k t} c_{N,s} \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz , $$
and optimization leads to
$$ c_{N,s} k^{-1} \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz , $$
which behaves in a completely different way.

---

### Conjecture

So a natural conjecture is that
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{u^\epsilon(x)}{\epsilon} = \frac{c_{N,s}}{k} \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz . $$
It should not be very difficult to write down a rigorous argument. In particular, I expect that the non-local case is far simpler than the local one.

My guess is that the above result follows relatively easily from what is known and can be found in literature, but, again, I do not have any particular reference in mind at this moment.

---

Final remark: my guess is that Varadhan's result, as well as the above conjecture, require an exterior cone condition, or something similar.

---

### PDE approach

*Edit: Here is a more PDE-oriented approach.*

Suppose that $u$ is the solution of
$$ u + \epsilon (-\Delta)^s u = 0 \qquad \text{in } \Omega $$
and $u = 1$ in the complement of $\Omega$. Let $w = u$ in $\Omega$ and $w = 0$ in the complement of $\Omega$. Then, at least formally, we have
$$ (\epsilon^{-1} I + (-\Delta)^s) w(x) = c_{N,s} \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} \frac{1}{|y - x|^{N + 2 s}} \, dy =: g(x) $$
in $\Omega$, and therefore $w$ is the resolvent for $(-\Delta)^s$ in $\Omega$ applied to $g$:
$$ u(x) = w(x) = \int_\Omega \biggl(\int_0^\infty e^{-t/\epsilon} p_t^\Omega(x, y) dt\biggr) g(y) dy ;$$
here $p_t^\Omega(x,y)$ is the heat kernel for $(-\Delta)^s$ in $\Omega$. (This is a very informal derivation of what is essentially the Ikeda–Watanabe formula in probability.)

Now let us rewrite the expression for $u$ a bit. We have
$$ \frac{u(x)}{\epsilon} = \int_\Omega \biggl(\int_0^\infty e^{-s} p_{\epsilon s}^\Omega(x, y) dt\biggr) g(y) dy .$$
Now let us write $u = u^\epsilon$ and consider $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Intuitively it is clear that the expression in brackets converges to the Dirac delta at $x$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Making this rigorous requires some effort, but since the first part was already informal, let me ignore all details. We find that
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{u^\epsilon(x)}{\epsilon} = \int_\Omega g(y) \delta_x(dy) = g(x) ,$$
which is precisely the conjectured result.

Comment: Time permitting, I'll think about references. As $s \to 1$, the constant $C(s)$ will converge to zero, so in a sense we do recover the local case in a very weak form. :-) This is one of the numerous results where there is a "phase transition" at $s = 1$. The simplest one (and one that is closely related to this question) is the estimate of the heat kernel: for a fixed $t$, it is $(1+|x|)^{-N-2s}$ when $s < 1$, but $\exp(-|x|^2)$ when $s = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it also strange that the right-hand side in the conjecture does not seem to satisfy the boundary condition $u^\epsilon =1$ in $\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega$?

Comment: I think this works as expected: $u^\epsilon / \epsilon$ is equal to $1/\epsilon$ in the complement of $\Omega$, and this goes to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: Thanks! Formally, is it clear that $\lambda^{-1}\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)^{-2s} $ solves the limit equation $\lambda u = 0$ in $\Omega$ and  $u=\infty$ in $\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega$?

Comment: I cannot parse your question: the only solution of $\lambda u = 0$ is of course $u = 0$, is it not? By the way, I realise the "$\dist(x,\partial \Omega)$" term is not quite correct, I'll update the answer momentarily.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is it then true that $I(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz $ satisfies $I(x) = 0$ for $x \in \Omega$ and $I(x) = \infty$ for $x \in \mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega$?

Comment: @Jun: I believe if you read what you just wrote carefully, you will realise right away that $I(x) > 0$. :-)

Comment: Thanks! But as $\epsilon \to 0$, we formally get that the limit of $u^\epsilon/\epsilon$ should solve $u= 0$ in $\Omega$ and $u=\infty$ in $\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega$. Is this right?

Comment: Hello. In the end, did you find the reference for the estimate on $\mathbb E^x e^{-k\tau_D}$?

Comment: I had no time to think about that, but it looks like one can get a two-sided bound by using two-sided estimates of the heat kernel $p_t^D(x,y)$; note that $\mathbb E^x e^{-k\tau_D} = \int_0^\infty \int_D e^{-kt} p_t^D(x,y) dy dt$. For the bounds on $p_t^D$, see [DOI:10.4171/JEMS/231](https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/231) and [DOI:10.1214/10-AOP532](https://doi.org/10.1214/10-AOP532).

Comment: This does not give exact asymptotics, just a two-sided bound. Asymptotics for a given point should be much easier, but as I said before, I do not have a reference. You may like to check papers by Bogdan, Byczkowski and co-authors, and by Chen, Song and co-authors, from 1997–2005.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. One thing remains unclear to me: at the PDE level, at least formally, how does one obtain this result? This is related to the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390439/formal-asymptotics-for-fractional-laplacian (and to some extent to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390207/explicit-formula-for-deltas-left-int-mathbb-rn-setminus-omega-x)

Comment: There you go. This is very informal — I could add more details if you like when I have time, but this will not be before schools in Poland are open again. :-)

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect. What is the change of variables that leads from the PDE for $u$ to the one for $w$? I guess $w = u - 1_{\Omega^c}$, if so is $g(x) = (-\Delta)^s 1_{\Omega^c} $?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (I would not call this "change of variables", though.) A word of caution: neither $w$ nor $\mathbb{1}_{\Omega^c}$ belongs to any of the usual domains of $(-\Delta)^s$ (at least not if $s > \tfrac12$). I'm not experienced in applying PDE methods, but I suppose making all of this rigorous is not straightforward.

Comment: I see. Thanks! By the way, is an $\epsilon^{-1}$ missing in front of $g(x)$? Otherwise (formally), we would get $w = 0$ in the limit

Comment: We do have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} u^\epsilon(x) = 0$, just as in the classical case. It is only the rate of convergence that changes: exponential of $-1/\epsilon$ in the classical case, and linear in $\epsilon$ in the non-local case.

Comment: I see. And then $u^\epsilon/\epsilon \to g(x)$. But I'm maybe missing a piece: from $$ \epsilon^{-2} w + \epsilon^{-1} (-\Delta)^s w(x) = \epsilon^{-1} g(x) $$ we also get $w/\epsilon \to 0$ instead of $\to g(x)$?

Comment: Also, about $1_{\Omega^c}$ not being in the domain of $(-\Delta)^s$: I know that usually one requires a zero condition on $\Omega^c$, but haven't nonhomogeneous fractional problems been studied?